# Sticky menu not appearing in Iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-safari, moodle

i've created a simple sticky menu using Bootstrap 3. However, it is not appearing in one of the testing phones. I've used several different phones (both Iphones and Android devices) with no issues, except for this particular thing. That being said, i've already cleared the cache and everything i could do to make it work.

I'm very open to suggestions, as it is not related to the code, nor the platform.

Comment: what is the phone you are referring to ? what is the code ? post an example !! iphone has many versions!

Comment: sorry, this can be erased